# Synchronizing database update/checking for bidding platform

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a platform on php/mysql that allows users to but for a percentage of a product. Basically they choose what percentage they want to bid for and the markup price they'd like to bid at e.g. 1.2.

The issue I have is that if there are several bids placed simultaneously for the same product, I need to queue the bids so when processed only the valid ones go through. For example, if there is 20% available at a value of 1.2 and two users simultaneously bid for 20% at 1.2, the process for each bid would be:
1----- select current bids
2----- php processing to work out if bid is still available
3----- place bid

The issue here is if both of the 'check if availables' happen before either of the 'place bids' then both bids will go through and effectively cause a stock issue.

Is there a way of queuing this process so the whole of steps 1-3 happen for a bid before the next one can run.

My initial thought was to use a cache table to store all the bids and then run a cron every few seconds which will process in order of ID from the cache table and notify accordingly but this seems like it may not be viable on a high traffic system as the server would get hammered over it.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Read about transactions and locks (in mysql)

Comment: as there is a php layer between the check and the update the format of the database doesnt really matter as 2 queries have to be run for any 1 bid, the first to check if their is availability and the second to actually place the bid. As the place bid is adding a new row not just updating an existing one then the face a row is locked will not make a difference

Comment: this should be solved by database, because specifically database provides all the tools to deal with high concurrency (they are transactions and locks)

Comment: that is how I would usually do it yes, but I am dealing with N number of rows in the tables, so I need to check my update vs N rows and then add new row based on results with some mathematical processing in between. If you are saying it is possible to write a mysql query that can select multiple rows from one table, process the results and then add a new row if suitable all from one query.....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this at PHP level by injecting the bid as an 'accepted bid' first so that any subsequent bids would fail. Then I ran the check to see if the bid was ok, if not the bid gets removed, if it is the table gets updated as required in place for new bids.

Answer (score 0):

If two bids can never be identical I would solve it at the data layer. Create a unique key on your bid table based on item_id, bid_value and whatever else needs to be unique. The second insert will fail and you can let user know they were beaten to the post

Comment: nice idea but unfortunately there is the possibility for bids to be the same, if there is 100% available at the start of an auction it is perfectly viable for 2 users to both place 10% bids at 1.2 as this would leave 80% available at 1.2